# How can I change the height of the drop down box in a Google Charts category filter

Tags: css, google-visualization

I have a Google Charts dashboard with various filters.  One of the filters has 300 options.

When I click on the filter the dropdown list box expands way outside the dimensions the data table.

Does anyone know the class, to which I can apply a height property, so that I get scroll bar within the drop down box.

I've tried to inspect the element and I thought my best shot was the class .goog-menu goog-menu-vertical

but that doesn't seem to affect it

I've enabled "allowHTML" in the options of the wrapper - just need to know a class....

thanks

Comment: I ran into this problem a while back, was never able to get a decent result, now I use [jquery ui selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/), wrapped in [jquery ui accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/), instead...

Comment: Thanks.  That's one to look at - I'm pretty far down the line now though... :/

Comment: I have never worked with this library so I changed their demo and created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39gtoh2m/), is this what you mean?

Comment: Ha! Brilliant yes that's perfect.  I can't believe I didn't try .goog menu but did try .goog menu goog-menu-vertical.  Too many hours at this one!! thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a potential solution to what you are looking for in the Google Groups forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/VilEBO0m3xI

Add the following to your style/CSS:

```
.goog-menu-vertical {
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I think you also need to have `cssClass` in the [`ControlWrapper`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) and `allowHtml: true` in your code for it to work.

Hope this helps! It did for me :)

**EDIT:** just noticed that @Alon Eitan provided the answer in the comments section... :) I'll leave my comment here for others to see better